# converting format (from date to numeric) using SAS

Tags: sas

I am working with a dataset in SAS, containing many variables.

One of these variables is a DATE variable and it has a date/time format. It looks like this:

```
12FEB97:00:00:00  
27MAR97:00:00:00  
14APR97:00:00:00
```

Now the thing is that I would like to convert this variable into a NUMERIC format. And I would like to get the following result (based on the previously shown 3 examples):

```
199702  
199703  
199704
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it? I already read through many docs, pdfs etc. but still could not find a proper solution yet.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you need to extract the date from your datetime variable. You can use the `datepart` function:

```
 date = datepart(var);
```

Then, you want to put this variable (which will still be coded as a date number) into a number that you can read the year and month. Do this with `putn`:

```
date_as_num = putn(date,'yymmn6.');
```

Comment: Wonderful, it is working, wonderful! Thank you very much dear itzy, you cannot even imagine how happy I am right now :)

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, I've been hunting for this solution for a few hours now. Simple and concise.